# Emacs -- How to extract all elements of a list

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am looking for some assistance, please, to extract all elements of a list of files and/or directories that have been marked in `dired-mode`.  Essentially, if there were some way to just remove the parentheses from around the result of `(mapcar (lambda (filename) (file-name-nondirectory filename)) (dired-get-marked-files))`, then that would do the trick.

```
(start-process
  "name-of-process"
  "*output-buffer*"
  "/usr/bin/zip"
  "zip-file-name.zip"
  (mapcar
    (lambda (filename) (file-name-nondirectory filename))
    (dired-get-marked-files)) )
```

The result I am seeking will look like this:

```
(start-process
  "name-of-process"
  "*output-buffer*"
  "/usr/bin/zip"
  "zip-file-name.zip"
  "filename-number-one"
  "filename-number-two"
  "filename-number-three" )
```

---

**EDIT**:

The `start-process` function does not generally accept a single concatenated string of arguments.  Instead, each argument must be separately spelled out (with quotation marks around each argument), *or* the argument can be a variable.

Here is the debugger message from the first example above -- **the error occurs because there is a parentheses around the file names** -- i.e., it cannot be a list.

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument stringp ("file-name-number-one" "file-name-number-two" "file-name-number-three"))
  start-process("name-of-process" "*output-buffer*" "/usr/bin/zip" "zip-file-name.zip" ("file-name-number-one" "file-name-number-two" "file-name-number-three"))
  eval((start-process "name-of-process" "*output-buffer*" "/usr/bin/zip" "zip-file-name.zip" (mapcar (lambda (filename) (file-name-nondirectory filename)) (dired-get-marked-files))) nil)
  (cons (eval exp lexical-binding) values)
  (setq values (cons (eval exp lexical-binding) values))
  (let ((debug-on-error old-value)) (setq values (cons (eval exp lexical-binding) values)) (setq new-value debug-on-error))
  (let ((old-value (make-symbol "t")) new-value) (let ((debug-on-error old-value)) (setq values (cons (eval exp lexical-binding) values)) (setq new-value debug-on-error)) (if (eq old-value new-value) nil (setq debug-on-error new-value)))
  (if (null eval-expression-debug-on-error) (setq values (cons (eval exp lexical-binding) values)) (let ((old-value (make-symbol "t")) new-value) (let ((debug-on-error old-value)) (setq values (cons (eval exp lexical-binding) values)) (setq new-value debug-on-error)) (if (eq old-value new-value) nil (setq debug-on-error new-value))))
  (let ((exp (if exp exp (read--expression "Eval: ")))) (if (null eval-expression-debug-on-error) (setq values (cons (eval exp lexical-binding) values)) (let ((old-value (make-symbol "t")) new-value) (let ((debug-on-error old-value)) (setq values (cons (eval exp lexical-binding) values)) (setq new-value debug-on-error)) (if (eq old-value new-value) nil (setq debug-on-error new-value)))) (let ((print-length (and (not (= 0 (prefix-numeric-value insert-value))) eval-expression-print-length)) (print-level (and (not (= 0 (prefix-numeric-value insert-value))) eval-expression-print-level)) (deactivate-mark)) (if insert-value (with-no-warnings (let ((standard-output (current-buffer))) (prog1 (prin1 (car values)) (if (= 0 ...) (progn ...))))) (prog1 (prin1 (car values) t) (let ((str (eval-expression-print-format ...))) (if str (princ str t)))))))
  (if (active-minibuffer-window) nil (let ((exp (if exp exp (read--expression "Eval: ")))) (if (null eval-expression-debug-on-error) (setq values (cons (eval exp lexical-binding) values)) (let ((old-value (make-symbol "t")) new-value) (let ((debug-on-error old-value)) (setq values (cons (eval exp lexical-binding) values)) (setq new-value debug-on-error)) (if (eq old-value new-value) nil (setq debug-on-error new-value)))) (let ((print-length (and (not (= 0 ...)) eval-expression-print-length)) (print-level (and (not (= 0 ...)) eval-expression-print-level)) (deactivate-mark)) (if insert-value (with-no-warnings (let ((standard-output ...)) (prog1 (prin1 ...) (if ... ...)))) (prog1 (prin1 (car values) t) (let ((str ...)) (if str (princ str t))))))))
  lawlist-eval-expression()
  funcall-interactively(lawlist-eval-expression)
  call-interactively(lawlist-eval-expression nil nil)
  command-execute(lawlist-eval-expression)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want is to use `apply` with `(mapcar ...)` as its last argument:

```
(apply 'start-process
       "name-of-process"
       "*output-buffer*"
       "/usr/bin/zip"
       "zip-file-name.zip"
       (mapcar #'file-name-nondirectory (dired-get-marked-files)))
```

Note that `(mapcar #'function list)` is a shorter spelling of `(mapcar (lambda (arg) (function arg)) list)`.

Comment: Yowza.  That's much cleaner that way.

Answer (score 2):

[`combine-and-quote-strings`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Shell-Arguments.html#Shell-Arguments) is what you want:

```
(combine-and-quote-strings (mapcar (lambda (x)
                                     (file-name-nondirectory x))
                                   (dired-get-marked-files)))
```

*EDIT*: the following will give you a single, quoted string with internal quotes.  Not sure if it'll play nicely with `start-process`:

```
(mapconcat
    (lambda (x)
      (concat "\"" (file-name-nondirectory x) "\""))
    (dired-get-marked-files) " ")
```

*EDIT*: Righty-o, let's try this.  Splice the backquoted list with `,@`, then `eval` the whole thing:

```
(eval `(start-process
        "name-of-process"
        "*output-buffer*"
        "/usr/bin/zip"
        "zip-file-name.zip"
        ,@(mapcar
           (lambda (x)
             (file-name-nondirectory x))
           (dired-get-marked-files))))
```

Comment: The files need to be quoted separately because `start-process` is very finicky -- i.e., every argument needs to be *individually* spelled out with quotation marks around each argument, unless it's a variable (which is already self-quoting).  The result needs to please look like this:  `"file-name-number-one" "file-name-number-two" "file-name-number-three"`

Comment: The `mapconcat` option may work, but I don't know if `start-process` will accept it.

Comment: `mapconcat` creates one string (with quoted strings inside it) -- one string (containing multiple quoted strings) will not work with `start-process` -- it needs to be a different string for each argument (or file name in this example).

Comment: Here is the process buffer readout when using `mapconcat`:  `zip warning: name not matched: "file-name-number-one" "file-name-number-two" "file-name-number-three"`  `zip error: Nothing to do! (zip-file-name.zip)`  `Process name-of-process exited abnormally with code 12`

Comment: Tried splicing it this time.  Any help?

Comment: I ended up opting for the `(apply . . .` solution.  I do really appreciate you having taken the time to work on this thread.  Your solution with `(eval . . .,@ . . .` does indeed work also -- so both are technically correct.